# Trouble w/ popup when extending leaflet Marker

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to extend the leaflet Marker class to create a location marker.  My location marker consists of an inner circle that represents the users location and an outer circle that represents the accuracy of the user location.  I am extending the class as I want to show a lot of users locations and I do not want to have to create 2 markers for each user.

I am having problems getting the popup to work though.  Two things:

1. the popup does not work, i.e. never shows up.
2. can I bind the popup to only the inner circle (users location), and not the outer circle (accuracy)

Here is a plunk, blue marker is standard circle with popup, green is my extended marker, popup does not work.
http://plnkr.co/edit/5tz538?p=preview

code:

```
L.LocationMarker = L.Marker.extend({
  initialize: function (latlng, options) {
    L.Marker.prototype.initialize.call(this, latlng);

    this._accuracyCircle = L.circle(latlng, 0, {
      color: options.color,
      fillColor: options.color,
      fillOpacity: 0.15,
      weight: 2,
      opacity: 0.5
    });

    this._locationMarker = L.circleMarker(latlng, {
      color: options.color,
      fillColor: options.color,
      fillOpacity: 0.7,
      weight: 2,
      opacity: 0.9,
      radius: 5
    });

    this._location = L.layerGroup([this._accuracyCircle, this._locationMarker]);
  },

  addTo: function (map) {
    map.addLayer(this._location);
    return this;
  },

  onAdd: function (map) {
    this._map = map;
    map.addLayer(this._location);
  },

  onRemove: function (map) {
    map.removeLayer(this._location);
  },

  getLatLng: function() {
    return this._locationMarker.getLatLng();
  },

  setLatLng: function (latlng) {
    this._accuracyCircle.setLatLng(latlng);
    this._locationMarker.setLatLng(latlng);
    return this;
  },

  setAccuracy: function (accuracy) {
    this._accuracyCircle.setRadius(accuracy ? accuracy : 0);
    return this;
  }
});

L.locationMarker = function (latlng, options) {
  return new L.LocationMarker(latlng, options);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it.  I had to override the popup methods to only handle the locationMarker.

```
bindPopup: function (content, options) {
this._locationMarker.bindPopup(content, options);
    return this;
},

setPopupContent: function (content) {
this._locationMarker.setPopupContent(content);
    return this;
},

unbindPopup: function () {
this._locationMarker.unbindPopup();
    return this;
},

_movePopup: function (e) {
this._locationMarker.setLatLng(e.latlng);
}
```

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/5tz538?p=preview